# $SO(3)$ vs 3-Torus

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

$SO(3)$ and 3-Torus both can be viewed via rotations for a rigid body. They are not diffeomorphic. $SO(3)$ can be decomposed into three axial rotations. Could I think the reason they are not diffeomorphic is because these axial rotations (via Euler angels) are constrained on one another unlike  ${S1}^3$ where the rotations are free of each other? I know there are other arguments but want to know if this is one way of thinking of it. I can explain more, if it is not clear what I mean.

Comment: Remember that rotating $\pi$ around the axis given by $\mathbf v$ is the same as rotating $-\pi$ about the axis given by $-\mathbf v$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I get it. thanks.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187176/2451